# python 3 print function

Tags: python, printing, line, new-operator

So I want to print this:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

And my code is:

```
for row in range(1,6):
    for col in range(row): 
        print('*', end="")
    print('')
```

My question is about print function, since it includes new line. Knowing some C before, I just can't figure it out what the last print('') does, and why my code doesn't work without it.

Comment: `print('*' * row)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `end=''` parameter to the first call to `print` suppresses printing a newine after the `*`, and the second call to `print` prints only a newline.

Answer (score 0):

The extra print line is shorthand for `print(end='\n')`

Answer (score 0):

Since you know C, here's your program in C. You can see that your code prints one character at a time and the "empty" print call results in a newline being printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    for (int row = 1; row < 6; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < row; col++)
            putchar('*');
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default python’s print() function ends with a newline. A programmer with C/C++ background may wonder how to print without newline.

Python’s print() function comes with a parameter called ‘end’. By default, the value of this parameter is ‘\n’, i.e. the new line character. You can end a print statement with any character/string using this parameter.

```
print("Python" , end = '@')  
print("Shubham")
```

**Output:**
    Python@Shubham